# Scalable actions with async/await

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I'm quite new with programming and I'm working on my first self-project, it's a forum I'm creating with ASP.NET MVC 5 and I'm trying to learn from it. 
I read a lot here and in MSDN about async actions in MVC I have several questions that I couldn't figure out.

1. As I understood, the IIS assigns x threads to each process, 2 for example. And every thread can deal with 1 request. When I mark an action as async and wrap the return type with task, the thread assign a worker to handle the request and report the IIS that it is free now to handle another request. So if a thread can create 3 workers, my action can serve 6 requests. Right?

   As I understood, an async method must await another async method in order to be truly async, if not, the method will run synchronically. So my question is, when exactly the thread assign this worker? When a request comes or when the awaited method is being called?
2. Again as I understood, every async method is being assigned to a worker, so if my website has 6 workers to spare (from the above question), will the amount of workers the can handle requests decrease as I use more and more async methods?
   For example, if I have an async action that calls asynchronically to `GetUser` and inside `GetUser` it calls asynchronically to `GetUserHistory` and inside `GetUserHistory` it calls asynchronically to `GetLoginData` will that action "waste" 4 workers that could have serve requests?
3. If all of the above is true, wouldn't it be scalable-effective to mark the action as async and make all the methods in my project sync methods and at the end of the action (or in the beginning) just await `Task.Delay(0)` so I will "waste" only one worker?

I see the questions and I think that there is something fundamental I didn't understand.

Comment: You may find my [async on ASP.NET article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) helpful.

Comment: @StephenCleary, great article! It really helps to clear up some of the fog

Comment: I second that, @StephenCleary, that was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.As I understood, the IIS assigns x threads to each process...

It can be more granular than that.  There are Machine settings, IIS settings, App Pool/Domain settings.

Trying to understand what a thread does makes it very very difficult to understand what is happening.  Instead think about it per request.  Each request uses a minimum of one thread.  In an Async controller method, if the runtime determines that there is a valid opportunity to thread context switch (await on an IO operation for example) the continuation of the request may be serived by another thread.

So when Request A comes in, Thread A start fulfiling the request.  If Thread A calls an IO async operation, [ExecuteReaderAync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync(v=vs.110).aspx) for example) there is a machine state that keeps track of what that thread is doing when the Async operation occurs.  Thread A becomes clear to start fulling another request (B).  When the machine state (or whatever it is) determines a thread is needed to continue the request (A), Thread A or some other thread takes the machine state and continues the request.

> will the amount of workers the can handle requests decrease as I use more and more async methods?

Under normal circumstances, no, you actually free up threads that would be normally wait for an IO operation to complete to service additional requests.  Adding async to a method does not change the threading model of that method, it only denotes to the runtime that it may run into an opportunity to "suspend" the current operation.

> 3.If all of the above is true...

It's not, so the assertion doesn't matter.

> why will the async method call other threads to handle the request?

An `async` method does not change how the threading works, only using `await` does.

> I mean, only async methods will trigger a new thread

No this is also wrong.  Neither `async` nor `await` *starts* a new thread in your code.

Example:

```
public async ActionResult MyMethod()
{
  await DoIt();

  return View();
}

public async void Doit()
{
  await DoMore();
}

public async void DoMore()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

This code will only always use one thread.  We aren't spawnings/using additional threads (maybe from the threadpool), we are using machine states to release the thread in `DoMore()` to fulfill other requests.  The same thread may or may not start and finish this request.

**Update**

Suppose you could setup your .Net application to only every use a single thread.  Without async when Request 1 started and waited 20 seconds to finisht the request, Request 2 would wait for a thread to become available (or get a 500, IIS Thread Starved).

[image: ASP.Net MVC Sync]

Now instead, you configure your controller and methods to make async calls down to an `await SomeSqlAyncMethod()`, the thread is free to response to request 2 and return html.  Once the SQL call is completed, the thread is then reused to complete request 1.

[image: ASP.Net MVC Async]

Comment: Thanks @Eric, the example you wrote, really cleared up some thing for me and if I understand you correctly, there are no workers involved, there are only threads that switch places every time an async method is being called. So where is the scalability? If x threads are handling my app, what does it matter which one is free to fulfill a request or the other?
And from what you say, there is a point in what I said about keeping the async methods calls to minimum in order to potentially use less threads and keep as many of them free to serve requests, right?

Comment: `where is the scalability` if a thread is blocked on `ExecuteReaderAync()` because it's running a 30 second query, then that thread is litterally doing nothing, waiting from results from SQL server.  That is not scalable.  Instead when the same method is called async with await, the thread is now free to do whatever is needed in the App Pool/Domain.  The more you take advantage of Async calls, the more threads can potentionally become free to serve other requests.  That is more scalability over the same hardware/software.

Comment: Added my skill at creating a flowchart in MsPaint for a visual.

Comment: Please take a look at [Stephen Cleary's blog - Async and Await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) it contains an immense amount of informaiton on the subject.